# Get dates between two dates and return resources available in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, php-carbon

I have a bit of an odd query that I need to run in Laravel.

I need to get each day from the current date until the next two weeks, then based on those days I need to return resources that are available for each day. When I use a single date as my start and end date it works, but on multiple days it doesn't return any resource.

First in my controller I create a range of dates like this:

```
$availabilityRange = CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->addDays(14)->startOfDay());
```

For a single date with the start of the day and end of the day I retrieve it like this and it brings back resources not booked for that date only:

```
$start_date = Carbon::tomorrow()->startOfDay();
$end_date = Carbon::tomorrow()->endOfDay();
```

Then I loop through my bookings to check which resources are available like this:

```
$resource = Resource::join('resource_teachers', 'resources.id', '=', 'resource_teachers.resource_id')
          ->where('resource_teachers.subject_id', $id)
          ->where('resource_subjects.deleted_at', NULL)
          ->select("resources.name", "resources.surname", "resources.id")
          ->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
            $query
              ->select(DB::raw(1))
              ->from('bookings')
              ->whereRaw('bookings.resource_id = resources.id')
              ->where(function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                $query
                  ->whereRaw('bookings.resource_id = resources.id')
                  ->where('bookings.start_date', '<=', $start_date)
                  ->where('bookings.end_date', '>=', $start_date);
              })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                $query
                  ->whereRaw('resource_id = resources.id')
                  ->where('bookings.start_date', '<=', $end_date)
                  ->where('bookings.end_date', '>=', $end_date);
              })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                $query
                  ->whereRaw('resource_id = resources.id')
                  ->where('bookings.start_date', '>=', $start_date)
                  ->where('bookings.end_date', '<=', $end_date);
              });
          })
          ->get();
```

And then I display the resources in my blade file like this:

```
@foreach($availabilityRange as $date)
  <tr>
    <td>
       {{ $date->toDateString() }}
        </td>
         <td>
          @if(($date == $start_date))
           @foreach($resource as $availableResource)
            <div class="badge badge-primary mr-1 mb-1">{{ $availableResource->name }} {{ $availableResource->surname }}</div>
             @endforeach
           @endif
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

If I try and get the resources for multiple days like this, it displays nothing:

```
$start_date = new DateTime(Carbon::now()->startOfDay());
$end_date   = new DateTime(Carbon::now()->addDays(14)->startOfDay());
```

I also tried this with no avail:

```
foreach ($availabilityRange as $start_date) {
  $start_date->startOfDay()->toArray();
}

foreach ($availabilityRange as $end_date) {
  $end_date->endOfDay()->toArray();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For a single day, you are getting the start and the end date like this:

```php
$start_date = Carbon::tomorrow()->startOfDay();
$end_date = Carbon::tomorrow()->endOfDay();
```

But for multiple days you are getting them like this (with the `DateTime`):

```php
$start_date = new DateTime(Carbon::now()->startOfDay());
$end_date   = new DateTime(Carbon::now()->addDays(14)->startOfDay());
```

To run your query, you want a `Carbon` instance, so try changing the above code to this:

```php
$start_date = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$end_date   = Carbon::now()->addDays(14)->startOfDay();
```

See also `whereDay()` and other where clauses you might find useful in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

#### Added:

See also your stacked `where()->orWhere()->orWhere()...`, I think you need to change some variables and conditions, for example:

```php
->where(function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
    $query
        ->whereRaw('bookings.resource_id = resources.id')
        ->where('bookings.start_date', '<=', $start_date) // should be  >=
        ->where('bookings.end_date', '>=', $start_date); // should be $end_date and <=
})
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it only brings back a resource for the first day and not for the other days.

Comment: Gotcha - see my addition above